# Creating a new column in pandas dataframe with selective values based on condition on another row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, finance

I have a dataframe (df) with 10 columns of Prices of company share prices with associated data. The index has many different dates, however there are multiple identical dates (and it is sorted by date). Additionally the important columns for this problem are df['Cond1'] and df['Cond2'] and df['Returns'].

Here is an example of the data with 3 columns for only 2 index values (1/21/2017 and 1/22/2017), in reality there are multiple dates with multiple variables etc etc.

```
            Name    Cond1   Cond2   Returns
1/21/2017   Apple       2   4   0.052450819
1/21/2017   Blackberry  6   5   0.423446578
1/21/2017   Microsoft   3   2   0.073850562
1/21/2017   IBM         1   1   0.966576931
1/21/2017   Ubisoft     5   7   0.371786953
1/21/2017   Next        4   3   0.58357725
1/21/2017   Marks and Spencer   2   7   0.466737922
1/21/2017   Alpha       4   3   0.291305661
1/21/2017   Right move  6   2   0.206502435
1/21/2017   Topsy       7   5   0.655331635
1/21/2017   Pizza hut   4   7   0.295723144
1/21/2017   Mcdonalds   3   4   0.338535647
1/22/2017   IBM         2   3   0.975326708
1/22/2017   Next        1   5   0.70893239
1/22/2017   Alpha       1   3   0.362154048
1/22/2017   Blackberry  6   2   0.664525792
1/22/2017   Apple       6   6   0.363531989
```

Now I want to create two columns ['Returns2'] and ['Returns3']

Returns 2 = new column in dataframe which only shows the returns for the date and 12 periods forward for that particular company if Cond1 < Cond2.

Returns 3 = new column in dataframe which only shows the returns for 1 day ahead and for 12 periods forward from that day for that particular company if Cond1

So ultimately I want to have 12 consecutive returns for 12 days for the company which satisfied Cond1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an approach like this:

```
df = df.set_index('Name', append=True).swaplevel().sort_index()
df.loc[df.Cond1< df.Cond2, 'returns2'] = True
df.returns2 = df.groupby(level=0).returns2.transform(lambda x: x.ffill(limit=12))
df.returns2 = df.returns2.mask(df.returns2.notnull(), df.Returns)
df.returns2
Name                  
Alpha       2017-01-21          NaN
            2017-01-22     0.362154
Apple       2017-01-21    0.0524508
            2017-01-22     0.363532
Blackberry  2017-01-21          NaN
            2017-01-22          NaN
IBM         2017-01-21          NaN
            2017-01-22     0.975327
Mcdonalds   2017-01-21     0.338536
Microsoft   2017-01-21          NaN
MnSpencer   2017-01-21     0.466738
Next        2017-01-21          NaN
            2017-01-22     0.708932
Pizzahut    2017-01-21     0.295723
Rightmove   2017-01-21          NaN
Topsy       2017-01-21          NaN
Ubisoft     2017-01-21     0.371787
Name: test, dtype: object
```